# Making all Mockito mocks verbose

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a longish test that uses the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` runner and defines a dozen of mocks using `@Mock' annotation, e.g.:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest() {
  @Mock Type1 name1;
  @Mock Type2 name2;
  @Mock Type3 name3;
  @Mock Type4 name4;
  @Mock Type5 name5;
  // etc.

  //tests
}
```

How can I make all the mocks verbose, ideally with the smallest number of code changes? I guess this is a common problem, I need to debug the issues with the test, but then I want to revert to normal (non-verbose) mocks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do so manually for now.

There is no global or annotation-based setting for this:

- The `@Mock` annotation can only have compile-time constants for properties, and there don't seem to be any regarding common settings or combinations thereof (other than `extraInterfaces`, `serializable`, `name`, and `defaultAnswer`).
- `initMocks` doesn't take any extra configuration settings.
- This is not a detail exposed through `MockingDetails`, so you couldn't reflectively iterate across your test class and change the mocks after they've been created.